# What is the solution to the following trigonometric integral equation?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, trigonometric-integrals

What is the solution for $s$ in the following integral equation
$$h = \int_{0}^{s}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\sin(x)+c)^3}$$
where $h$ and $c$ are constants.

Maple and Mathematica can compute the integral but then solving for $s$ requires finding a root of a complicated trigonometric expression.

If there are no closed form expressions for $s$ then are there fast and accurate numerical approximations for finding $s$? (I.e. faster than: (1) doing Newton iterations on the resulting non-linear system; and (2) solving the integral using quadrature and stopping when the integral equals $h$)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean about $h$ being constant; doesn't it depend on $c,\,s$? Also, what do you mean by solving for $s$? Do you want to express $s$ as a function of $h,\,c$?

Comment: The indefinite integral is given by $$\frac{\left(2 c^2+1\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c \tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right)}{\left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}+\frac{\cos
   (x) \left(4 c^2+3 c \sin (x)-1\right)}{2 \left(c^2-1\right)^2 (c+\sin (x))^2}$$

Comment: You will need a numerical method for the computation of $s$. Concerning possible approximations, I shall work on it tomorrow morning (it is dinner time here). By the way, **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: Are $c >1$ and $h >0$ ? Please answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, h is a positive constant that does not depend on x nor c. I'd ideally like to have an explicit expression for s in terms of h and c, and we can assume c>1.

Comment: @BenTapley. Explicit expression : no way. What I did provide will be very fast to converge. By the way, if you consider that this is an answer to your problem, may be you could accept it in order other users know it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the antiderivative, the equation you need to solve for $s$ is
$$h=A+B\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c \tan
   \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right)+\frac{\cos (s) \left(4 c^2+3 c \sin (s)-1\right)}{2 \left(c^2-1\right)^2 (c+\sin
   (s))^2}$$
Where
$$A=-\frac{\sqrt{c^2-1} \left(4 c^2-1\right)+2 c^2\left(2c^2+1\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right)}{2 c^2 \left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}\qquad B=\frac{\left(2 c^2+1\right) }{\left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}$$
This assumes a bunch of conditions
$$(s\notin \mathbb{R}\lor \Re(s)\leq \pi )\land ((\Re(c \csc (s))\geq 0\land c \csc
   (s)\neq 0)\lor$$ $$ c \csc (s)\notin \mathbb{R}\lor \Re(c \csc (s))\leq -1)\land
   c+\sin (s)\neq 0$$

The rhs presents discontinuities at $(2k+1)\pi$ and we can just focus on the first one.

Now, the problem is with $h$. If it is positive, a look at the curves for any $c > 1$ shows that the range of $h$ is quite limited since the maximum value of the rhs is
$$\text{max}=\frac{\sqrt{c^2-1} \left(c \left(2 c \left(\pi  c
   \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2-1}}-4\right)+\pi 
   \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2-1}}\right)+2\right)-2c^2\left(2 c^2+1\right) \cot
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{c^2-1}\right)}{2 c^2 \left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}$$
$$\text{min}=\frac{\sqrt{c^2-1} \left(2-c \left(2 c \left(\pi  \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2-1}}
   c+4\right)+\pi  \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2-1}}\right)\right)-2c^2 \left(2 c^2+1\right)
   \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{c^2-1}\right)}{2 c^2 \left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}$$ and, in order to have solution, we need ${min} < h < {max}$.

Where the problem is nice is

- if $h > 0$, compute the straight line joining points $(0,0)$ and $(\pi,max)$
- if $h < 0$, compute the straight line joining points $(\pi,min)$ and $(2\pi,0)$

Interpolating along these lines will give a starting guess for Newton method.

Trying for $c=2$ for which $max=\frac{4 \sqrt{3} \pi -15}{36}$ and 
$min=-\frac{15+8 \sqrt{3} \pi}{36}$

Being lazy, I started at the midepoint

- for the first case, I used $h=\frac 34 max$ and the iterates are
  $$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
  n & s_n \\
   0 & 1.57080 \\
   1 & 2.83934 \\
   2 & 2.64193 \\
   3 & 2.61501 \\
   4 & 2.61462
  \end{array}
  \right)$$
- for the second case, I used $h=\frac 34 min$ and the iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & s_n \\
 0 & 4.71239 \\
 1 & 4.44687 \\
 2 & 4.43695 \\
 3 & 4.43691
\end{array}
\right)$$

This seems to work quite well.

**Update**

Assuming $h > 0 $, we can do a few more things. First, name $f(s)$ the rhs of the equation in the top.

Better than what I wrote earlier, the maximum value  is given by
$$f(\pi)=\frac{1-4 c^2}{c^2 \left(c^2-1\right)^2}+\frac{\left(2 c^2+1\right) \sec ^{-1}(c)}{\left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}$$

The interesting properties are listed in the table below

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
s & f(s) & f'(s) & f''(s) \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c^3} & -\frac{3}{c^4} \\
 \frac{\pi }{2} & \frac{1}{2}f(\pi ) & \frac{1}{(c+1)^3} & 0 \\
 \pi  & f(\pi ) & \frac{1}{c^3} & \frac{3}{c^4}
\end{array}
\right)$$ which (for sure) shows the symmetry at $s=\frac \pi 2$. This could probably be the base information for some interpolating function (as a polynomial, it would be of quite high degree and then no interest). Another possible solution would be to use the data in the above table to fit a cubic equation in $s$ without the constant term (this is how looks $f(s)$ in $[0,\pi]$) but the problem is to decide about the respective weights to be assigned to the function and derivative values. I am still working on it but it would then require  solving the cubic in $s$ using the hyperbolic method.

For the time being, using linear interpolation between the end points
$$s_0=\frac {\pi}{f(\pi)} h$$ For the worked case $\big[c=2 , h=\frac 34 f(\pi)\big]$, this will give $s_0=\frac {3 \pi}  4$ and Newton iterates would then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & s_n \\
 0 & 2.35619 \\
 1 & 2.64598 \\
 2 & 2.61514 \\
 3 & 2.61462
\end{array}
\right)$$

Ignoring the values of the second derivative and giving the same weights to the other values, the cubic polynomial $\alpha s+\beta  s^2+\gamma  s^3$was generted minimizing the sum of the squred residuals. The formulae are really messy and will not be printed here.

For the worked example, the result from the cubic would be $s=2.62062$.

**New update**

For a better *estimate*, for $0 \leq h \leq  \frac{1}{2}f(\pi )$, using the following data

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
s & f(s) & f'(s) & f''(s) \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c^3} &  \\
 \frac{\pi }{2} & \frac{1}{2}f(\pi ) & \frac{1}{(c+1)^3} & 0 
\end{array}
\right)$$

we can write the rhs as $$f(s)\approx\frac{\alpha s+\beta s^2}{ 1+\gamma s+ \delta s^2}$$ and the parameters $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ are totally explicit (the formulae are easy to establish) and the *estimate* is obtained at the price of a quadratic equation in $s$.

Furthermore, it is worth to mention that, using [this](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html) with the simplistic $s_0$, a single iteration leads almost to the solution. Let $s_{(n)}$ the result for the worked example.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & s_{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 1 & 2.6459758 & \text{Newton} \\
 2 & 2.6130746 & \text{Halley} \\
 3 & 2.6140472 & \text{Householder} \\
 4 & 2.6148101 & \text{no name} \\
 5 & 2.6146006 & \text{no name}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, Claude! So your idea here is to create a cubic interpolating polynomial in $s$, which is guess results in solving a small linear system. Then solve this polynomial using the "hyperbolic method"... I haven't heard of this method but am I correct to assume that you are referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root ?

Comment: @BenTapley. This problem is just fascinating to me ! I did not stop working it and I still work. The problem would be to solve the cubic (have look at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cubic_function&oldid=915111262#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root . I "hope" that we could avoid it. If your problem was for very small $h$ or values close to $f(\pi)$, I have solutions (or almost). In fact, what would be good is to build an interpolating function (may be not a polynomial even if the curves look like) which could be inversed. If I have something new, I shall post it.  Cheers.

Comment: Don't forget that Newton works like a charm for this problem.

Comment: I'm trying to create a numerical method for integrating a volume-preserving ODE and the last step is we need to solve this integral at each time step, $h$ (which arises from a time-transformation $t\rightarrow s$). As we are going to compare this method to explicit methods, an efficient evaluation of the integral is what I'm after. So if the equation at the top can be efficiently evaluated by finding the real root of a cubic polynomial then that would certainly be better than Newton iterations, would you agree? Can you also explain how a cubic is a good fit for $f(s)$ for $s\in[0,\pi]$?

Comment: I'm glad you're enjoying it! Yep, so $h<<1$ is the time-step in "physical time", and $s$ is the transformed time.

Comment: @BenTapley. What is important to me is : how large can be $\frac h {f(\pi)}$ ?

Comment: I don't think you can put a bound on $\frac{h}{f(\pi)}$, but I'll have a closer look and let you know if I find anything. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the new update, Claude. Interesting that it does so well after only one iteration! I'll have a closer look at this and reply when I understand everything. But how come we are replacing $f(s)$ with a rational function? How do you find the interpolation weights (alpha, beta, gamma and delta) in this case? 

By the way I don't think you can put a bound on $\frac{h}{f(\pi)}$ but I think you can assume it is small (or at least less than $1/2f(\pi)$), like you have done.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to write a separate answer.*

Using the tangent half-angle substitution $x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$, we have
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{(\sin(x)+c)^3}=2\int \frac{ \left(t^2+1\right)^2}{\left(c t^2+2 t+c\right)^3}\,dt$$ Partial fraction decomposition leads to
$$f(t)=\int \frac{ \left(t^2+1\right)^2}{\left(c t^2+2 t+c\right)^3}\,dt=\frac{\left(2-c^2\right) t+c}{c^3 \left(c^2-1\right) \left(c t^2+2 t+c\right)^2}+$$
$$\frac{c\left(5 c^2-2\right)  t+(4 c^4-3 c^2+2) } {2 c^3 \left(c^2-1\right)^2 \left(c t^2+2 t+c\right) }+\frac{\left(2 c^2+1\right) }{2
   \left(c^2-1\right)^{5/2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c t+1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right)$$ making that we need to solve
$$\frac h 2+f(0)=f\left(\tan \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\right)$$ which is not bad.